# Facebook photo tagging app not tagging people

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook photo tagging app that used to work a few months ago but no longer does. The user authenticates the app and it uploads a picture on their facebook account and tags their friends. The app uploads the picture but stopped tagging for some reason.

```
require_once('facebook.php');

$_SESSION['init'] = true; $current_date=date('m/d/Y');   $facebook =
new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
  'cookie' => true,   
));   

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true); 
$session = $facebook->getSession();   $tokenorig =
$facebook->getAccessToken();

$friends =
  file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token="
  . $tokenorig);

$friends = json_decode($friends, true);
$friends = $friends['data'];

foreach($friends as $friend) {
  $uids[] = $friend['id'];
} 

function makeTagArray($userId) {
  $x=1; $y=1;

  foreach($userId as $id) {
    $tags[] = array('tag_uid'=>$id, 'x'=>$x,'y'=>$y);
    $x+=1;
    $y+=1;
  }

  $tags = json_encode($tags);
  return $tags; 
}


$arguments = array(
  'message' => 'hi guys ',
  'tags' => makeTagArray($uids),
  'source' => '@' .realpath('pic2.jpg'),
);

$alb = "13378";
uploadPhoto(
  $facebook, 
  $alb, 
  $arguments,
  $tokenorig);

function uploadPhoto($facebook,$albId,$arguments,$tokenorig) {
  //https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos
  try {
    $fbUpload =
      $facebook->api('/'.$albId.'/photos?access_token='.$tokenorig,'post',
      $arguments);

    return $fbUpload;
  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo "eror";
    echo $e;
    // var_dump($e);

    return false;
  } 
}
```

//////////end

Comment: Judith, can you please use the code "{}" button next time for code and make sure that the code is properly formatted so that its easy to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First off all, 
You need user's to authorize your application to upload photos and tag on behalf of them and
you need publish_stream and user_photos permissions to tag user's friends